# Python library that can watch a folder for changes and copy the changed files to another directory

Tags: library, python

Is there a Python library that can watch a folder for changes and copy the changed files to another directory, i.e. something like rsync?

The Python libraries that I can see online are very old, i.e. early 2000s

Comment: Do you want a pure python solution, or do you want it to use rsync...

Comment: i want pure python solution